# Convert hex characters in text with php built-in function

Tags: php, hex, decode, encode

Is there a built-in PHP function to convert hex characters in text?

This:

```
$encoded="this is \x7Btext\x7D";
```

to

```
$decoded="this is {text}";
```

Answer (score -2):

You have nothing to do, `\x7B` and `\x7D` are already interpreted as `{` and `}` between double quotes.

`\x7B` is the hexadecimal ascii code for `{`
`\x7D` is the hexadecimal ascii code for `}`

A character can have several representations between double quotes or with the heredoc syntax (literal, hexadecimal, octal).

Try:

```
echo "this is \x7Btext\x7D this is {text} this is \173text\175";
```

and *(hexadecimal)*

```
var_dump("this is \x7Btext\x7D" === "this is {text}");
```

or *(octal)*

```
var_dump("this is \173text\175" === "this is {text}");
```